# Sencha Touch 2 - data sync to localstorage taking too much time

Tags: performance, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, synchronization

I'm using sencha touch 2 for my mobile app. I'm loading json data from a web-server to a sencha touch local store (localStorage). There are more than 5000 data and it takes 15+ minutes to load data to local store. Initially I'm getting all data into a data store using proxy and then I'm copying all data to a local store so that data will be available offline. I have tested, json response comes inside half minutes, but all the remaining time takes when I use sync() function to copy (add) data to local store. Also when sync process is in progress, whole app stuck at that point. Following are the code lines,

```
memberStore.each(function(item){                    
      memberLocalStore.add(item);
});
memberLocalStore.sync();
```

Can anyone please tell me the reason for this, why sync function taking too much time to save data to localStorage? And is there any solution to reduce this time?

Comment: From my experience, using localStorage for saving a big amount of data is not a good choice. The problems were not during saving data, but also after closing app at 'wrong time'. If you are using native wrappers in your app, may be you should look at the side of native SQLite databases. Or may be Web SQL Database can show better perfomance.

Comment: check here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995492/sencha-touch-sync-store-performance-issue/24139101#24139101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly save data in your local database spare table than load all data in store it will increase your app performance.

for more detail click below link 
[sencha touch Sync store Performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995492/sencha-touch-sync-store-performance-issue/24139101#24139101)